# C++ GUI App: Starting a child process in WndProc ( no MFC )

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface, process

I have been having trouble starting a child process in my GUI application. Below is my WndProc. I would like the ID_TOOLS_NEWPROCESS case to start a new process which will open the dialog box. Will this will allow the main window to remain responsive when the new window opens?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
int wmId, wmEvent;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc;

switch (message)
{
case WM_COMMAND:
    wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
    wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
    // Parse the menu selections:
    switch (wmId)
    {
    case IDM_ABOUT:
        DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
        break;
    case IDM_EXIT:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
    case ID_TOOLS_NEWPROCESS:
        DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_NEWBOX), hWnd, NEW);
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    break;
case WM_PAINT:
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    // Draw text in the main window
    TextOut(hdc, 10, 10, L"Main Window",11);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}
```

I hope I have explained that clearly, Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

- Dan.

**EDIT:**
@Roger Stewart

The about is using the following as its message pump:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam,         LPARAM lParam)
{

UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
switch (message)
{
case WM_INITDIALOG:
    return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

case WM_COMMAND:
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK)
    {
        EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
    }
    break;
}
return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

The trouble here is that When the about box is open, the main window behind is unresponsive until the about box is closed. I would like to be able to open and control multiple dialog boxs with the main windows still being responsive.

**EDIT 2:**
This is the code I have now but I am still unable to select the main window with the about box open.

message handler for the about box:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
switch (message)
{
case WM_INITDIALOG:
    return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

case WM_ACTIVATE:
    if (0 == wParam)             // becoming inactive
        hDlgCurrent = NULL;
    else                         // becoming active
        hDlgCurrent = hDlg;
    return FALSE;

case WM_COMMAND:
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK)
    {
        EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
    }
    break;
}
return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Main message loop:

```
     while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
     {
     if (NULL == hDlgCurrent || !IsDialogMessage(hDlgCurrent, &msg))
        {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
     }
```

@David - could you possibly shed some light on why this is still not returning the desired result.

Comment: You don't need a new process to show a modeless dialog. Use `CreateDialog` and `ShowWindow`. Also, the new dialog will need its own message pump (its own WndProc).

Comment: @Roger Stewart I have updated my post with more information. If you could help me out further that would be great.

Comment: @Roger New dialog doesn't need its own message pump. It can use the main thread message pump. You must be using `IsDialogMessage` there though.

Comment: @L337BEAN You really really don't want a new process here. You just want to show a modeless dialog box, just as Roger says. But he is confusing matters when he says that WndProc is a message pump.

Comment: @David You may be right with using `IsDialogMessage`. I am having trouble getting it to work though. I have been trying with this [guide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/71450) but having no luck.

Comment: Is it possible that I need to use `CreateDialog()` instead of `DialogBox()` or will either do ?

Comment: DialogBox is for modal dialogs. Use CreateDialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @David. The solution was indeed to use `CreateDialog()` rather than `DialogBox()`

My program is now functioning as I would like it too.

-Dan.